# Can I include data declaration to another data?

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

I am writing CodinGame [hypersonic](https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/hypersonic) bot.

I have a working code for parse input

```
type Position = (Int,Int)

data Entity = Player { pId :: Int, pPos :: Position, pBombStock :: Int, pBombRange :: Int } 
            | Bomb { bOwnerId :: Int, bPos :: Position, bTimeLeft :: Int , bBombRange :: Int}
  deriving Show

-- The entityType will be:
--   For players: 0.
--   For bombs: 1.
-- The owner will be:
--   For players: id of the player ( 0 or 1).
--   For bombs: id of the bomb's owner.
-- The param1 will be:
--   For players: number of bombs the player can still place.
--   For bombs: number of rounds left until the bomb explodes.
-- The param2 is not useful for the current league, and will always be:
--   For players: explosion range of the player's bombs (= 3).
--   For bombs: explosion range of the bomb (= 3).
mkEnt :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Entity
mkEnt 0 o x y p1 p2 = Player { pId = o, pPos = (x,y), pBombStock = p1, pBombRange = p2}
mkEnt 1 o x y p1 p2 = Bomb { bOwnerId = o, bPos = (x,y), bTimeLeft = p1, bBombRange = p2}
mkEnt _ _ _ _ _  _  = error "invalid entity type"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ mkEnt 0 1 0 0 0 3
  print $ mkEnt 1 1 0 0 0 3
```

But when I try to refactor the `Entity`

```
data Entity = Player | Bomb
  deriving Show

data Player = Player { pId :: Int, pPos :: Position, pBombStock :: Int, pBombRange :: Int } 
  deriving Show

data Bomb = Bomb { bOwnerId :: Int, bPos :: Position, bTimeLeft :: Int , bBombRange :: Int}
  deriving Show
```

the code won't compile with `error: Multiple declarations of ‘Player’`

Do I need any language extension to make this work, or it can not be done (by designed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two constructors in the same module called `Player`, and the same with `Bomb`. You could give one of them a prefix like this to disambiguate the constructors:

```hs
data Entity = EPlayer | EBomb
  deriving Show
```

However, I don't think your `Entity` is doing quite what you want it to do. Those two constructors on `Entity` carry no data and have no relation to the data types `Player` and `Bomb`. If you wanted the `Entity` constructors to carry data, you could define them as such:

```
data Entity = EPlayer Player | EBomb Bomb
  deriving Show
```

But by that then, you are kind of in the same position where you started. What exactly are you trying to achieve by this refactoring?

Comment: I see, I think `Entity` would be easier to read due to less constructor noise. But will this one make pattern matching on `Entity` harder than my old working code? In that case I will use the working one.

Comment: If you move to the separate `Entity` type, then you will have to pattern match on `EPlayer` and `Player` everywhere in order to get the payload.